# IFrame Won't retain CSS Style

Tags: css, iframe

I have a  third party application that can host HTML in something it calls a container. In the container, we do the following:

```
    <meta content="IE=EmulateIE9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <iframe style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 640px" id="c_list" 
     src="/Path/ToMVC/ControllerPage" width="100%"></iframe>
```

In the _layout.cshtml that is used by ControllerPage, we hardcoded the links to the CSS in the head element. If I right click and pick "View Source", I can see the paths. Ex:

```
    <link href="/Project/Content/Sheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Despite all of the above, the CSS in Sheet.css is ignored/dropped/not used. When I view the "/Path/ToMVC/ControllerPage" URL in its own window, all the CSS renders without issue. How can I force the IFrame to stop dropping the CSS?

EDIT: Ok, I made a discovery. Using the F12 dev tools, I noticed the page using the IFrame was running in IE quirks mode instead of IE standards mode (Which is what the page is using when viewed outside of an IFrame). When I changed it to IE 9 Standards mode, all the CSS worked! Is there a way I can force the IFrame page to go with IE9 Standards instead of Quirks mode?

Comment: What is the CSS for the iFrame in sheet.css? Note that using `style="width:100%;"` AND `width="100%"` is unnecessary. Also, by default, any inline styles (e.g. `style="width:100%;"`) will take precedence over any styles from an external stylesheet. Though it is not recommended, you can override precedence rules by appending `!important` to any CSS property.

Comment: Sounds like a path problem, any 404's ins the console when opening the iframe?

Comment: @Jason, there are multiple CSS sheets I am trying to load. They are all related to the Kendo UI Library by Telerik. Sheet.css was just a dummy sample file.

Comment: @Nico, I am using Fiddler, which is confirming that the .css sheets are loading and not giving me a 404.

Comment: @Dave again, it's hard to know why CSS isn't working without being able to view the CSS. We need to see the code to better understand what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise, any answer we give will be speculation at best. Do any of the suggestions I gave apply to your issue?

Comment: @Jason. Hi Jason, I am starting to think it is not the CSS itself, but the way the browser is loading the page with the IFrame on it. Please see me edit to the question.

Comment: Use the HTML5 doctype, `<!DOCTYPE html>` also `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I think I have it narrowed down to what I need to do... My parent needs to run in Quirks mode, and my IFrame needs to run in IE9 Document mode. I am going to start a new question for that.